# Authentication in headers/fetch

Tags: javascript, async-await, http-headers, fetch-api

I am stuck and looking for someone to help me. I've been trying to Authorize my fetch request but it always return an error. Is there someone who could explain in what way authorize header?

```
import { ref } from "vue";

const getAllData = () => {
  const data = ref();
  const entry = "user:pass";

  const fetchAllData = async function () {
    const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        // How to authorize?
        Authorization: Bearer ${entry},
      },
    });
    data.value = await res.json();
    console.log(data.value);
  };
  return { data, fetchAllData };
};

export default getAllData;
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Hi,The error is:Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
127.0.0.1:8000/articles/:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
getAllData.js?3add:8

Comment: Learn about CORS policy and how to disable it properly. There are many ways